# Is there a way to use pyjnius in sl4a

Tags: android, python, sl4a, pyjnius

Hey guys is there any way of using pyjnius with sl4a?

By that I mean importing pyjnius and using it in a python sl4a script...

The goal is to be able to access the Google Play Services’ Activity Recognition client from an sl4a script.

Any other way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

There is QPython, which is a great concept, but on my particular device (Galaxy S4 with A 4.4 upgrade) SL4A is more stable than QPython...

If you wish to give QPy a try, download the QPython app from Play Store (I use the Python v. 2.X version), then in the app's settings download additional packages and one of them is a fully functional pyjnius, you can access ANYTHING you would from a java app, but inside the super convenient python environment, the guys behind QPy have done an incredible job, yet the interpreter often crashes, but this is not consistent across all of my devices and changes with QPy's updates.

To illustrate, I use pyjnius to access advanced TTS features of the OS not accessible to SL4A. There are a couple of good examples on QPy's site: https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius/blob/master/docs/source/android.rst, try https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Jwp1PTvECI, google for pyjnius android.